How to dynamically switch Python docstring based on flag in the code or sys environ
I've got a library which provides bunch of functions for the client. They can be accessed via:
from my_package import functions
functions.fun_a()

from my_package.functions import fun_b
fun_b()

Beneath that, are different private modules and the __init__, which imports everything from the private module as from _private_module import * n times for each module.
Now I need some sort of facade so that I can dynamically replace those functions on the run based on environment variable for instance:
# in my_package.functions
import os
if os.environ['some_var']:
    from implementation_a import *  # provides one inplementation of fun_a and fun_b etc.
else:
    from implementation_b import *  # provides different implementation 

Now the issue is that both will have the same API but might have slightly different docstring - for instance first implementation requires different type of environment and configuration to work with. Is there any way to let know for example Pycharm or other IDE when to use different docs for those functions? I would like to make it convinient for the future clients to switch between documentation A and B but also do not break any rules and make some ugly hacks.
Currently I've tried:
/my_package
    /functions
        __init__.py -> with from implementation A or B import * in if statment
        /implementation_a
            __init__.py -> imports all private submodules for client
        /implementation_b
            __init__.py -> same but different implementation

This does not work as IDE takes the docstrings from the last import statmenet and does not take the if/else block into account (quite expected as the code is not executed).
Another option just to reduce the size of files and
/my_package
    /functions
        __init__.py -> with from implementation A or B import * in if statment
        _some_functions.pyi -> empty functions with typing and docs for both
        _some_functions.py -> here goes the if/else with from imp A or B import *, this one is 
                              needed as pyi files must be next to the .py with same name or in 
                              different package if we want to provide interface from separate 
                              package (which we don't want to).
        /implementation_a
            __init__.py -> imports all private submodules for client
        /implementation_b
            __init__.py -> same but different implementation

It looks a little bit better but now I need bunch of private modules which does nothing more than just have the import in if/else clause. On the other hand we've got now interface and docstring in one place and implementation in another.
Do you have any other suggestions? Class called functions with static methods? We try to keep the code as much as it is now so the client will not have to change his code/imports etc. but rather make this switch dynamic, provide nice and clean docs AND at the same time I do not want to make any spaghetti code...

If the choice of private module changes the public interface, they aren't as private as you think. I would suggest refactoring so that your IDE doesn't need to know what's getting used based on the value of a runtime variable value.
